# Convert MySQL data to JSON and include MySQL count

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a custom database table for a WordPress site. I am trying to save the data from MySQL call to JSON. The table contains a date column. I would like to count how many times each date appears. I would then like to save the date and the number of times it appears into a JSON object. Here is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "rlwpentries";

$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date, count(date) FROM $table_name group by date" );

$data = array();
foreach ($query as $row) {
$data[] = array('date' => $row->date, 'count' => $row->count);
}

print json_encode($data);
```

Here are my results:

```
[  
    {  
        "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "count":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2019-02-22 00:00:00",
        "count":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2019-02-23 00:00:00",
        "count":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2019-02-24 00:00:00",
        "count":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2019-02-25 08:00:00",
        "count":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2019-02-26 00:00:00",
        "count":null
    }
]
```

Can someone explain how I can get the correct "count" value to show up in my JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the value first

```
SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS `count`
```